# How I can update a widget in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I create a desktop application that shows your PC parameters and I can't update a labels text, for example CPU current frecuency and other information.

The example is below.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import psutil
import platform
import cpuinfo
import sys

uname = platform.uname()
cpufreq = psutil.cpu_freq()
Physical_cores = psutil.cpu_count(logical=False)
Physical_cores = str(Physical_cores)
Total_cores = psutil.cpu_count(logical=True)
Total_cores = str(Total_cores)
Max_Frequency = (cpufreq.max)
Max_Frequency = str(Max_Frequency)
Max_Frequency = Max_Frequency +  "Mhz"
Min_Frequency = (cpufreq.min)
Min_Frequency = str(Min_Frequency)
Min_Frequency = Min_Frequency + "Mhz"
Current_Frequency = str(cpufreq.current)
Current_Frequency = Current_Frequency + "Mhz"
Total_CPU_Usage = psutil.cpu_percent()

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("project")
        MainWindow.resize(600, 520)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(4214422, 16777215))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(61, 61, 61);")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout_9 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout_9.setContentsMargins(6, -1, -1, -1)
        self.gridLayout_9.setObjectName("gridLayout_9")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold SemiConden")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.tabWidget.setFont(font)
        self.tabWidget.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.tabWidget.setStyleSheet("QTabWidget::pane{\n"
"  border: 1px;\n"
"  background:rgb(210,39,48);\n"
"}\n"
"QTabBar::tab{\n"
"  min-width:35px;\n"
"  min-heigth:10px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(61, 61, 61);\n"
" color:rgb(210,220,24);\n"
"}\n"
"QTabBar::tab:selected{\n"
"  background: rgb(65, 65, 65);\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"QTabBar::tab:hover{\n"
"\n"
"color:rgb(190,200,4);\n"
"}")
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.CPU = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.CPU.setStyleSheet("border:none;")
        self.CPU.setObjectName("CPU")
        self.gridLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.CPU)
        self.gridLayout_4.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_4.setSpacing(0)
        self.gridLayout_4.setObjectName("gridLayout_4")
        self.scrollArea_2 = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.CPU)
        self.scrollArea_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        self.scrollArea_2.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea_2.setObjectName("scrollArea_2")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 583, 460))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents_2")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 11, 0, -1)
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(4)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.label_15 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2)
        self.label_15.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(180, 0))
        self.label_15.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(180, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold SemiConden")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_15.setFont(font)
        self.label_15.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(80, 80, 80);\n"
"color:rgb(210,220,24);\n"
"font-family: Bahnschrift SemiBold SemiConden")
        self.label_15.setObjectName("label_15")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_15, 7, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_17 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2)
        self.label_17.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(180, 0))
        self.label_17.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(180, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold SemiConden")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_17.setFont(font)
        self.label_17.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(80, 80, 80);\n"
"color:rgb(210,220,24);\n"
"font-family: Bahnschrift SemiBold SemiConden")
        self.label_17.setObjectName("label_17")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_17, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_24 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2)
        self.label_24.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(180, 0))
        self.label_24.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(180, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold SemiConden")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_24.setFont(font)
        self.label_24.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(80, 80, 80);\n"
"color:rgb(210,220,24);\n"
"font-family: Bahnschrift SemiBold SemiConden")
        self.label_24.setObjectName("label_24")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_24, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_23 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2)
        self.label_23.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(180, 0))
        self.label_23.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(180, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold SemiConden")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_23.setFont(font)
        self.label_23.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(80, 80, 80);\n"
"color:rgb(210,220,24);\n"
"font-family: Bahnschrift SemiBold SemiConden")
        self.label_23.setObjectName("label_23")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_23, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_21 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2)
        self.label_21.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(180, 0))
        self.label_21.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(180, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold SemiConden")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_21.setFont(font)
        self.label_21.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(80, 80, 80);\n"
"color:rgb(210,220,24);\n"
"font-family: Bahnschrift SemiBold SemiConden")
        self.label_21.setObjectName("label_21")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_21, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2)
        self.label.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(180, 0))
        self.label.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(180, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold SemiConden")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.PreventContextMenu)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(80, 80, 80);\n"
"color:rgb(210,220,24);\n"
"font-family: Bahnschrift SemiBold SemiConden")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 9, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_16 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2)
        self.label_16.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(180, 0))
        self.label_16.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(180, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold SemiConden")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_16.setFont(font)
        self.label_16.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(80, 80, 80);\n"
"color:rgb(210,220,24);\n"
"font-family: Bahnschrift SemiBold SemiConden")
        self.label_16.setObjectName("label_16")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_16, 6, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_20 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2)
        self.label_20.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold SemiConden")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_20.setFont(font)
        self.label_20.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(80, 80, 80);\n""color:rgb(210,220,24);\n""font-family: Bahnschrift SemiBold SemiConden")
        self.label_20.setObjectName("label_20")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_20, 4, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_19 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2)
        self.label_19.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold SemiConden")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_19.setFont(font)
        self.label_19.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(80, 80, 80);\n""color:rgb(210,220,24);\n""font-family: Bahnschrift SemiBold SemiConden")
        self.label_19.setObjectName("label_19")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_19, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_18 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2)
        self.label_18.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold SemiConden")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_18.setFont(font)
        self.label_18.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(80, 80, 80);\n""color:rgb(210,220,24);\n""font-family: Bahnschrift SemiBold SemiConden")
        self.label_18.setObjectName("label_18")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_18, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_22 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2)
        self.label_22.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold SemiConden")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_22.setFont(font)
        self.label_22.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(80, 80, 80);\n""color:rgb(210,220,24);\n""font-family: Bahnschrift SemiBold SemiConden")
        self.label_22.setObjectName("label_22")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_22, 6, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_25 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2)
        self.label_25.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold SemiConden")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_25.setFont(font)
        self.label_25.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(80, 80, 80);\n""color:rgb(210,220,24);\n""font-family: Bahnschrift SemiBold SemiConden")
        self.label_25.setObjectName("label_25")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_25, 7, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2)
        self.label_4.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold SemiConden")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(80, 80, 80);\n""color:rgb(210,220,24);\n""font-family: Bahnschrift SemiBold SemiConden")
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_4, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2)
        self.progressBar.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 60))
        self.progressBar.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold SemiConden")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.progressBar.setFont(font)
        self.progressBar.setStyleSheet("QProgressBar\n""{\n""    font-family: Bahnschrift SemiBold SemiConden;\n"
"    color:rgb(210,220,24);\n"
"    background-color: rgb(54, 54, 54);\n""    text-align:left;\n""    \n""}\n""QProgressBar::chunk\n""{\n"
"    background-color: rgb(80, 80, 80);\n""}")
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", psutil.cpu_percent())
        self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.progressBar, 9, 1, 1, 1)
        self.scrollArea_2.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2)
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.scrollArea_2, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.CPU, "")
        self.info = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.info.setObjectName("info")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.info)
        self.gridLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.info)
        self.scrollArea.setStyleSheet("border:none;")
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 583, 460))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.gridLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, -1, 0, -1)
        self.gridLayout_3.setSpacing(4)
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.scrollArea, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.info, "")
        self.Rom = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.Rom.setStyleSheet("border:none;")
        self.Rom.setObjectName("Rom")
        self.gridLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.Rom)
        self.gridLayout_7.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_7.setSpacing(0)
        self.gridLayout_7.setObjectName("gridLayout_7")
        self.scrollArea_3 = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.Rom)
        self.scrollArea_3.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea_3.setObjectName("scrollArea_3")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 583, 460))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents_4")
        self.gridLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4)
        self.gridLayout_8.setContentsMargins(0, -1, 0, -1)
        self.gridLayout_8.setSpacing(4)
        self.gridLayout_8.setObjectName("gridLayout_8")
        self.scrollArea_3.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_4)
        self.gridLayout_7.addWidget(self.scrollArea_3, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.Rom, "")
        self.about = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.about.setStyleSheet("")
        self.about.setObjectName("about")
        self.gridLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.about)
        self.gridLayout_6.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_6.setSpacing(0)
        self.gridLayout_6.setObjectName("gridLayout_6")
        self.scrollArea_4 = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.about)
        self.scrollArea_4.setStyleSheet("border:none;")
        self.scrollArea_4.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea_4.setObjectName("scrollArea_4")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_6 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 583, 460))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_6.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_6.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents_6")
        self.gridLayout_10 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_6)
        self.gridLayout_10.setContentsMargins(0, -1, 0, -1)
        self.gridLayout_10.setSpacing(4)
        self.gridLayout_10.setObjectName("gridLayout_10")
        self.scrollArea_4.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_6)
        self.gridLayout_6.addWidget(self.scrollArea_4, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.about, "")
        self.GPU = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.GPU.setStyleSheet("border; none")
        self.GPU.setObjectName("GPU")
        self.gridLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.GPU)
        self.gridLayout_5.setContentsMargins(0, -1, 0, -1)
        self.gridLayout_5.setObjectName("gridLayout_5")
        self.scrollArea_5 = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.GPU)
        self.scrollArea_5.setStyleSheet("border: none\n""")
        self.scrollArea_5.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea_5.setObjectName("scrollArea_5")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 583, 438))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents_3")
        self.gridLayout_11 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3)
        self.gridLayout_11.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_11.setSpacing(4)
        self.gridLayout_11.setObjectName("gridLayout_11")
        self.scrollArea_5.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3)
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.scrollArea_5, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.GPU, "")
        self.gridLayout_9.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_15.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Current Frequency"))
        self.label_17.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Max Frequency"))
        self.label_24.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Processor"))
        self.label_23.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Physical cores"))
        self.label_21.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Total cores"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Total CPU Usage"))
        self.label_16.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Min Frequency"))
        self.label_20.setText(_translate("MainWindow", Max_Frequency))
        self.label_19.setText(_translate("MainWindow", Total_cores))
        self.label_18.setText(_translate("MainWindow", Physical_cores))
        self.label_22.setText(_translate("MainWindow", Min_Frequency))
        self.label_25.setText(_translate("MainWindow", Current_Frequency))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", cpuinfo.get_cpu_info()['brand_raw']))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.CPU), _translate("MainWindow", "CPU"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I tried to use loops but it didn't work.

Comment: Note that you're **not** expected to edit pyuic generated files (as clearly written in the header you ignored and removed), doing so is considered bad practice and almost anything you'll eventually ask when having problems after editing those files will result in a closed question for the same reason. Please regenerate the file again, and properly follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).